# VBA duplicated declaration in "if...else"

Tags: vba

Simple as below:

```
If 1 = 2 Then
    Dim i As Integer  
Else
    Dim i As Integer
End If
```

This will give an error as "duplicated declaration in current scope". Why?

Comment: Because you duplicated the declaration in the same scope. An if block in VBA doesn't create a localized scope.

Comment: @user614244 If an answer solves you problem, you should accept it by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables are local to the sub/function (procedure). In your case, the "current scope". VB, VBA, and VBScript do not have the concept of code blocks within a procedure. If I remember correctly, the only code blocks are modules, classes, forms (which are classes), and procedures.

You can declare a variable anywhere within the procedure as a convenience. Yet, the "current scope" is the procedure.

It was a design decision to make the language easier to use for **B**-eginners.

---

*Duplicate declaration in current scope*

> The specified name is already used at this level of scope. For
>   example, two variables can have the same name if they are defined in
>   different procedures, but not if they are defined within the same
>   procedure.

Inserted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251613.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, declarations of two variables with the same name cannot be made in the same procedure.  See this article for more information: [Duplicate declaration in current scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251613.aspx).

In your case, the "current scope" is the current procedure.  The `if` and `else` blocks share the same scope.

For example, the following will give the same error even though the second declaration is unreachable:

```
Sub ErrorSub()
    Dim i As Integer

    If False Then
        Dim i As Integer
    End If
End Sub
```

But the following is perfectly valid and will work fine:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 4
    MsgBox i
End Sub

Sub MyOtherSub()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    MsgBox i
End Sub

Sub CallSubs()
    MySub
    MyOtherSub
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you cannot have more than one Dim statement for a variable with the same scope.  Aside from that, however, why would you want to?  Take your code for example.

```
If 1 = 2 Then 
    Dim i As Integer   
Else 
    Dim i As Integer 
End If
```

The purpose of a conditional block is to execute two different pieces of code under two different circumstances.  If you are declaring the same variable either way, there is no need for the conditional block at all.  In all likelihood, it should probably be moved before the conditional.