# VBA how do I test if a variable exists and if not then set it?

Tags: vba

I found a similar question asked but it didn't quite answer my question. Here is the link to the other question: [VBA duplicated declaration in "if...else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388991/vba-duplicated-declaration-in-if-else)

I want to test if a variable exists. If it does, I want it to be set to false, otherwise I want to declare it and then set it to false. Here is the code:

```
    If SR1 Is Nothing Then
        Dim SR1 As Boolean
        SR1 = False
    Else
    SR1 = False
    End If
```

I understand that I cannot declare this code in the current scope but how can I accomplish the same logic? 
I would like the variable to be applicable to another sub that will test if it is true/false. This is in the initialization sub of my form that clears all fields in my form and resets certain values. I also have a "clear form" button that runs the initialization sub when clicked. In this regard, my code block is run multiple times and I can't simply declare the variable.

Comment: Can you not use something like If 
    Dim SR1 As Boolean
    if SR1 <> trueThen
         SR1 = False
    End If

I supose the question really is do you just always need this variable set to false unless it is set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a global form variable.  If this is the case, then what you want to do is declare it OUTSIDE of your subs.

So:

```
 Private SR1 As Boolean

 Sub Form_Load()
       SR1 = False 'or set it however you want
 End Sub

 Sub mySub1()
      SR1 = False
      .......
 End Sub
 Sub mySub2()
     If SR1 = False Then
     ......
     Else
     ......
     End If
 End Sub
```

Note that "Nothing" is the uninstantiated state of an Object variable (see here: http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html).  A boolean is not an object, and when it has not been "instantiated" is initially set to false, so, technically, you wouldn't even need to set it to false in the load form, as it will already be false when you open the form.

If you want to use the variable in a sub that is not in your form, then you either need to pass it as a parameter when calling the sub FROM your form, or declare it as a global variable in a module so that it will be in scope for the entire database.  You would need to make sure that you are setting it properly whenever you are using it, though.

Also note that I have made the variable Private.  If you make it public, then other forms will be able to access it, but this gives too much control to the other forms.  If you need to change the variable from another form, make a sub to do so, or if you need to access the value, make a function to return it.

Comment: I was under the impression that when declaring a variable it had to be declared in a sub in order to be declared. If that is not the case, are variables declared outside of the sub still declared when the form loads?

Comment: I just edited this as you should use "Private" or "Public" to declare it, not "Dim".  When the form loads, the variable will be automatically declared.  If it is not an object, then it will be the default value.  If it is an object, then it will be declared, but not instantiated until you set it in either a form_load event or other event.  If you hide the form, the variable will remain, but if you close the form, it will be gone until you reopen the form.

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up! :)
If I want to change the variable to true or set it to true, does this have to be within a sub?

Comment: Yes, you have to set it to true within a Sub.  I'd recommend initializing it within the Form_Load sub, that way whenever the form is opened it will be set.  It is possible to make constants, but then you can't change their values.